# Builder C++ creating STRINGTABLE in resource

Tags: resources, c++builder

I cannot find anywhere how to create a stringtable in Builder C++ 2010.  Do I have to use an external editor or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no resource editor built in to C++Builder 2010. You can easily add either a .res file built with another tool, or create a .rc file to add to your project and have the resource compiler create the resource. The following is an example of an .rc file which includes a string table

```
#define IDS_HELLO    1
#define IDS_GOODBYE  2

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_HELLO,   "Hello"
    IDS_GOODBYE, "Goodbye"
END
```

Comment: so how can i get the value of this resource string in my code? via TResourceStream ?