# get string from dll c++

Tags: c++, string, dll

I use eclipse and mingw compilier (c++).
I would like to create a dll file which contains a lot of strings.
After that I would like to call with `LoadString()` to read the string (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647486(v=vs.85).aspx)

my dll file:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define DLL_FUNC extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

DLL_FUNC int __stdcall Hello() {

    return 0;

 }
```

my cpp file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    int main () {

    typedef int (__stdcall *HelloProc)();

        HMODULE hdll = LoadLibrary("HelloWorld.dll");
        if( hdll == NULL){
            MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "Wrong dll path", "Message", MB_OK);
        }
        else {
            typedef int (__stdcall *HelloProc)();

            HelloProc Hello = (HelloProc)GetProcAddress(hdll, "Hello@0");
            if(Hello == NULL){
                //LoadString();
                MessageBox(HWND_DESKTOP, "Hello is NULL", "Message", MB_OK);
            }
            else{
                Hello();
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

How do I create the strings? And how to call with `LoadString()`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to read about *resources* so that you can build a resource-only DLL containing a string table.  Try searching the MSDN site you referenced for things like **resource compiler** and maybe **how to build a resource only DLL** and **how to use string tables**.  I'm sure you will find documentation and examples at Microsoft and, if not, with Google.

Oh, your DLL is not **required** to be resource only, I got that from your comment "I would like to create a dll file which contains a lot of strings."  It is actually even easier (maybe more *straightforward*) to do if your DLL will also contain code.  Then you'd want to search for **adding resources to a DLL** and things like that.

Comment: Stringtable would be good for me. But how to create string table in dll file? I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248786/builder-c-creating-stringtable-in-resource but if i compile this I get this error:
error: 'STRINGTABLE' does not name a type. I think its not enough in the dll file

Comment: @user1601401 you need to compile the resources with a _resource compiler_ as they are not part of C/C++.  You might need to download a full SDK from Microsoft (I think they're available for free) to get a copy, or there may be a copy in the SDK you already have.  Look for a program named `rc.exe` in your SDK folder tree, that will be it.